# Using bun with Azure DevOps registry gives 403 despite installing

Tags: azure-devops, npm-package, bun

I'm getting a 403 on the private packages from an Azure DevOps feed. The install still runs successfully, the error message looks like this:

```
 env-paths [748/781]
GET https://SERVER.blob.core.windows.net/BLOB_LINK - 403
```

I have a bunfig.toml that looks like the following:

```ini
[install.scopes]
"@SCOPE" = { username="ORG_NAME", password = "ACCESS_TOKEN", url = "https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/ORG_NAME/PROJECT_NAME/_packaging/FEED_NAME/npm/registry/" }
```

The token permissions were set like this:
[image: The permissions of the token]

I would expect either a fail of the install or no 403 - the current output is confusing.

Comment: The first link looks like from Azure Storage and the token is for Azure Artifacts Feed. These two are different products.

Comment: Yes, but Azure Artifacts are stored in Azure Storage.

Comment: But the token is used for Feed not the storage account. For Storage account if you want to access you should use SAS token. (but to be honest, I'm not sure what are you doing)

Comment: Trying to use https://bun.sh instead of npm for installing dependencies. I know this is still an early version and there are bugs to be expected. I was asking in case anyone has solved this before. If not - then so be it :D

Comment: did you figure this out? having same issue with fury.io and its _authToken

Comment: @LittleTiger As for Azure Artifacts, it's coming with Bun 1.0.3: https://twitter.com/jarredsumner/status/1704132615740297527

He also wrote a little guide: https://bun.sh/guides/install/azure-artifacts